# How to write set selected option in a dropdown from c#

Tags: asp.net, htmlwriter

im trying to achieve below html code from c#

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

my main goal is to do below line from c#

```
<option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
```

so far i have done below code

```
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
DataTable dt1 = BAL.setDropDown(tablename, id_col, value_col, hotel_id);
//let say selected_value is 1 
if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
    {
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Option);
        if( row[0].ToString() ==1 )
        {
             // i want to add selected on option tag here!!!
        } 
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, row[0].ToString());
        writer.Write(row[1].ToString());
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this:

```
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Selected, "selected");
```

It will render

```
<option value="saab" selected="selected">Saab</option>
```

which is acceptable by browsers.